# What are the ages of the Stark children at the beginning of A Storm of Swords

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

What are the ages of the Stark children at the beginning of A Storm of Swords?

Jon, Robb, Sansa, Arya, Brandon, and Rickon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Robb - 15 years old (Born 283AL)
2. Jon Snow - 14 years old (Born 283AL)
3. Sansa 11 years old (Born 286AL)
4. Arya - 9 years old (Born 289AL)
5. Brandon - 7 years old (Born 291AL)
6. Rickon - 3 years old (born 295AL)

All information taken from [this site](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Main_Page). It's been a while since I read the series, but I do remember some birthday celebrations in the book, which would explain the mathematical difference (theoretically according to year subtraction, Sansa should be 12).

Comment: Ha, I've been watching the show and reading the wiki's. Suddenly I understand why John Snow acts the way he does.

Comment: I have not seen the show, but from what I understand it is markedly different from the books.

Comment: @QueueHammer In the show all the children are several years older than in the books.

Comment: @Dima That is understandable given the scenes they had to shoot. (Robb and Talisa, Jon and Ygritte, Sansa and Ramsay)

Answer (score 1):

The Stark children are about 3 years older in the Tv series.  In the premiere episode, Catelyn says that 10 year old Bran is too young to witness an execution.

Comment: Cool! But what are the ages of the others (besides Bran)?

Comment: But the TV show is not the books - there are a whole slew of artistic license deviations between the two.